# Masterdata Services udpValidateModel Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, master-data-services

i've got a few tables in MDS.

One table (clients) ist filled via SQL and the other one is a masterdata table (country) filled by hand.

I have a business rule on table clients:

"Name must be unique" and no b-rule on Country.

I want to validate the data PROGRAMMATICALLY i do not want to CLICK "apply business rules" in explorer window on the webinterface.

I found several threads about how to use the sp mentioned in the title (udpValidateModel) to validate all entities in a model.

well...this thing does nothing. I can see the validationStatus in each of my tables "Awaiting Revalidation" after changing business rules or update data via sql. It doesnt matter what i do the status wont change (neither the validation icons in webui).

i also tried validateentity but the same "nothing" happens.

The SP below:

```
DECLARE @User_ID int 
DECLARE @Model_ID int 
DECLARE @Version_ID int 

SET @User_ID = (SELECT ID FROM [MasterDataServices].[mdm].[tblUser]  where userName = SYSTEM_USER )

SET @Model_ID = (SELECT Top 1 Model_Id  FROM [MasterDataServices].[mdm].[viw_SYSTEM_SCHEMA_VERSION]
                                WHERE Model_MUID = 'MYMODELID')

SET @Version_ID =   (SELECT Top 1 VersionNbr  FROM [MasterDataServices].[mdm].[viw_SYSTEM_SCHEMA_VERSION]
   WHERE Model_MUID = 'MYMODELID' 
                   ORDER BY ID DESC )

EXECUTE [MasterDataServices].[mdm].[udpValidateModel] @User_ID, @Model_ID, @Version_ID, 1
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

SP 'udpValidateModel' works perfectly fine, looks like the parameters you are populating is not correct.

You may correct this as below and try; make sure that the system user has full authorization for the model.

```
SET @User_ID = (SELECT ID FROM [MasterDataServices].[mdm].[tblUser]  where userName = SYSTEM_USER )
SET @Model_ID = (SELECT Top 1 Model_Id  FROM [MasterDataServices].[mdm].[viw_SYSTEM_SCHEMA_VERSION]
                 WHERE Model_MUID = 'MYMODELID')
SET @Version_ID =   (SELECT Top 1 VersionNbr  FROM [MasterDataServices].[mdm].[viw_SYSTEM_SCHEMA_VERSION]
                     WHERE Model_MUID = @Model_ID 
                     ORDER BY ID DESC )
```